# Problem with oersted's experiment of electric wire magnet deflection

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

Changing electric field induces magnetic field. But in oersted's experiment we see deflection of the magnet with constant current in wire. Does it oppose our concepts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing electric field induces magnetic field, but not only changing electric field induces magnetic field.

The fully description is given by the Maxwell's equation:

$$\nabla\times\vec B=\frac1c\left(4\pi\vec J+\frac{\partial\vec E}{\partial t}\right)$$

If the electric field does not change with time and the current density distribution is constant, as in Oersted's experiment, the second term vanishes but the first term is non-zero, meaning magnetic field still exist. Such magnetic field does not change with time, and hence cannot further induce electric field (to see this you need another equation from the Maxwell's set) to generate an electromagnetic wave, but it generates what is known as the [static magnetic field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetostatics) and remains constant over time.

Note that this is the Maxwell's equation in the vacuum using Gaussian units. If it is not in vacuum the equation will be more complex and the result can be different.